# LocalDb in asp.net project require some configurations to run on other machine? VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, localdb

I need to send a asp.net demo using SQL Server database. Is local db something require no configuration to run on other machine ? Is it something if I include in project, on other machine other person will just run application in Visual Studio and LocalDb will be available there ? or it will require some configurations on other machine as well ?

I m looking for a way there I can just add a database in my asp.net application and on other machine having visual studio should open and run it without any configuration. Please guide is LocalDb for this purpose or I should use any other solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the target machine should have [SQL Sever Express 2012/2014 LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh510202%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) installed. It comes with VS 2012 (as long as it was not deselected in the advanced options during setup).

Read more at [confusion about SQL Server Express and localdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547998/confusion-about-sql-server-express-and-localdb)

If you provide a demo for developers, you should list all requirements for the system, such as

- VS.NET version
- database engine version
- user rights, folder structure, etc.

and they should take that into account when setting the demo.

Comment: just installation is enought ? Or some other configurations will be required ?

Comment: can you please suggest some solution where on other machine no configurations are requried ?

Comment: A configuration may vary and you cannot be sure that their setup is equal to your setup. As I mentioned in the updated post, LocalDB comes with VS.NET2012. You should list all requirements for your demo and your clients should configure their machine appropriately.