# Migrate project to use localDB

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I just wrote application using sql server 2008 R2 and winforms.

As I can imagine, installator should create localDB file or sth like that and then use this as a database inside my app. Whats more I would like to include initial database file to my msi package.

What is the best way to do it right now ?

Comment: You do know that localDB is meant for development, not installation with your application? That is written clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **SQL Server Compact Edition** or **SQL Server Express** (which as I understand is embeddable). Here's a good SO answer about the difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17548422/394007