# Why do we use mostly LocalDB instead of SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, visual-web-developer

I am confused between localDB and SQL Server. What is actual difference between using LocalDB and SQL Server? And, which one is recommended?

Comment: What did your research show? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547998/confusion-about-sql-server-express-and-localdb, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571331/is-it-normal-to-use-localdb-in-production, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780941/sql-server-localdb-v11-0-explained

Comment: Such a broad question. Provide target, number of expected users and data size, type of application etc... Its like choosing between a bicycle and 747.

Comment: `LocalDB` ***IS*** SQL Server - in a developer-optimized edition. LocalDB is a version of SQL Server Express that doesn't install as a service on your machine, but is started up when your application starts (e.g. from within Visual Studio). But LocalDB ***IS*** SQL Server !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LocalDB** is a lightweight version of the SQL Server Express Database Engine that is targeted for program development. LocalDB starts **on demand** and runs in user mode, so there is no complex configuration or installation of a full blown DB engine.

From [Introducing LocalDB, an improved SQL Express](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/):

> LocalDB is created specifically for developers. It is very easy to install and requires no management, yet it offers the same T-SQL language, programming surface and client-side providers as the regular SQL Server Express. In effect the developers that target SQL Server no longer have to install and manage a full instance of SQL Server Express on their laptops and other development machines.